# How can ArrayLists in Groovy hold different types of values?

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

```
a = [1, "Hello", 3.5]

println a.getClass()
```

Yields

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

But isn't `ArrayList` only capable of holding one type of value? How can my `ArrayList` hold an integer, a string and a float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArrayList`s can hold any type of `Object`. The `int` and the `float` are autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Float`, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

> But isn't ArrayList only capable of holding one type of value? How can
>   my array hold an integer, a string and a float?

No, it's definitely not. Before [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) were introduced `ArrayList` was capable of holding any value type and different types at the same time. And what may be funny after generics were introduced it's still the same. Why? Because generics are only compile time and are removed at runtime - see [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). And because groovy as is JVM language it behaves as in your example.